# Viewing typedef replacement

Tags: c, typedef

Can anyone tell me, how can I see the typedef replacement string. 
Actually we could see the preprocessor replacement using `cc -E filename.c` . So like that I want to see the typedef replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (and also the `-E`) depends on the compiler you are using.

That said, I doubt this is possible with any compiler. Contrary to macros, typedefs are not just text replacements.

Please note also that the output of a potential typedef expanding program is not necessarily valid C code, e.g. instances the same struct will become incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

typedefs are not macros.

-E is a preprocessor stage in compilation and you will be able to see only MACRO replacements.

```
#define A int *
typedef int *B;
```

Now this means wherever 'A' appears, it will be replaced by 'int *' - plain string replacement
However B is synonymous to saying 'int *'

So when I type :

```
A c, d;
B e, f;
```

The -E stage will show you that the following replacement has taken place :

```
int *c, d;
B e, f;
```

So :

c is of type 'int *'
d is of type 'int'
e is of type B (synonymous to saying e is of type 'int *')
f is of type B (synonymous to saying f is of type 'int *')

HTH